# Has Facebook changed the "Dark" Color scheme for the Like Box?

Tags: facebook-like, color-scheme

I've had my "Like Box" color scheme set to "Dark" for months and all of a sudden it only displays in "Light" (used to be background black and text white).  I went to the developer page and it appears the Dark setting is not working the same for the demo either when settings are made for template. Has something changed with the plug-in? Did they change the "Dark" scheme to some kind of transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

i tried facebook developer page and i can get code for dark theme too

[see here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)
 code is something like

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

 <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

Comment: Yes thanks @Astha, I am aware the code is still working for the Dark Scheme but it appears that the colors of the scheme have changed. I was trying to find out if there was a bug or if Facebook has changed this intentionally.